# How to provide input parameter for SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Based on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx, I successfully execute the SQL that I coded in the SQL file via the following code:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

Now instead of executing a `SELECT` operation, I would like to have `UPDATE` operation. I'm wondering how to modify the above code so that it accept parameter and this parameter will be used in `myScript.sql`?

My sample `UPDATE` operation will be expected to be something like below:

```
UPDATE someColumn FROM someTable where tableID = @tableID;
```

So from the command, I will provide a `tableID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few methods. Some of them are described here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -v tableID ="your_val" -i C:\myScript.sql


UPDATE someColumn FROM someTable where tableID = $(tableID);
```

Answer (score 0):

With -v parameter

```
  -v @tableID = 1
```